# Dependiendo lo que eligas en el select te envia a una pagina o otra

Tags: php, html, html-select

Estoy intentando hacer una pagina y lo quiero es que dependiendo la opcion que elija en el select que tengo hecho abajo del select haya un boton y dependiendo de la opcion que elija me envie a una pagina o a otra.

Gracias de antemano.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="select">
  <option name="option1" value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option name="option2" value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option name="option3" value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

He hecho este select de prueba y quiero que por ejemplo si elijo "value1" haya un boton abajo del select que cuando le de click me envie a una pagina en especifico y si por ejemplo elijo "value2" me envie a otra pagina. Si se puede hacer con php mejor, lo he intentado hacer pero no lo he conseguido porfavor aydadme.

Gracias

Comment: Muestra el intento que haz echo.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con JS, te dejo una idea si te sirve https://jsfiddle.net/chvjgu13/1/

Comment: Yo lo he intentado hacer con php con un if pero como no se mucho php creo que no lo estoy haciendo bien.   <?php
$select = 'select';
$option1 = 'option1';
$option2 = 'option2';

if ($select[1]== $option1) {
    echo "<a href='form.php'>Empezar</a>";
} elseif ($select == $option2) {
    echo "<a href='main.php'>Empezar</a>";
} 


?> esto es lo que estuve haciendo pero nada.  @Cris223511.dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detalle esta que intentas cambiar del lado del cliente y para ello debes usar Javascript para que puedas acceder al cambio del select.

Te dejo tu código junto a una función para leer el cambio de estado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="select" id="select">
  <option name="option1" value="value1">Value 1</option>
  <option name="option2" value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option name="option3" value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>

<script>
function enviar()
{
   //Leemos el valor del select
   var valor=document.getElementById("select").value;
   
   //Comparamos para saber a que url lo enviamos
  if(valor=="value1"){
    window.location="url1.php";
  }
  if(valor=="value2"){
    window.location="url2.php";
  }
  if(valor=="value3"){
    window.location="url3.php";
  }  
}
</script>
```

En la función que te puse de **Enviar** lee el valor de tu select y te envia a la url que decidas (url1,url2 o url3).

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Josue Vargas me ha servido